# Could max introduce round-off error?

Tags: matlab, max, precision

In general, the == operator is not suited to test for "numeric" equality, but one should rather do something like `abs(a - b) < eps`. However, when I want to find the location of the largest element in an array, is it save to assume that `max` will return the element unchanged? Is it ok to do

```
[row, col] = find(a == max(a(:));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

`max` only compares two values, and does not do any operations on them that might change their values.

Here's a typical C++ implementation of a `max`:

```
template <class T>
T max(T a, T b) {
    return a>b ? a : b; 
}
```

As you see, this function will return the *exact* same value as either `a` or `b`.

Matlab just adds matrix formalism, fancy formatting wrappers etc. to it, but its kernel will follow the same principles as the example above.

So yes, it is OK to use equality here.

Comment: Thanks, also I like your C with templates ;-)

Comment: @Psirus: Yes, I call c++ "C-style", because it's in the "C" family of languages (as is Python, Java, ...). But OK, edited to prevent any pointless discussion with purists :p

Comment: This is C++! End of discussion! :)